# cloudera quick start load csv table hdfs with terminal

Tags: csv, hadoop, terminal, hdfs, cloudera

I am new to all this as I am only in my second semester and I just need help understanding a command I need to do. I am trying to load a local csv file to hdfs on cloudera using the terminal. I have to use that data and work with Pig for an assignment. I have tried everything and it still gives me `'no such file or directory'`. I have turned off safe mode, checked the directories and even made sure the file could be read. Here are the commands I have tried to load the data:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal 2008.csv
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal 2008.csv
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal 2008.csv /user/root
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal 2008.csv /home/cloudera/Desktop
```

Nothing at all has worked and keeps giving me

> '2008.csv' no such file or directory

. What could I do to fix this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to use that data and work with Pig for an assignment

You can run Pig without HDFS.

`pig -x local`

> I have tried everything and it still gives me 'no such file or directory'

Well, that error is not from HDFS, it seems to be from your local shell.

`ls` shows you the files available to use in the current directory for `-copyFromLocal` or `-put` to work without an absolute path.

For complete assurance for what you are copying, as well as *to where*, use full paths in both arguments. The second path is always HDFS if using those two flags.

Try this

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p  /user/cloudera # just in case 
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ./2008.csv /user/cloudera/
```

Or even

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/cloudera/Desktop/2008.csv /user/cloudera/
```

What I think you are having issues with, is that `/user/root` is not correct unless you are running commands as the `root` user, and neither is `/home/cloudera/Desktop` because HDFS has no concept of a `Desktop`.

The default behavior without the second path is

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal <file> /user/$(whoami)/
```

(Without the trailing slash, or a pre-existing directory, it'll copy `<file>` literally *as a file*, which can be unexpected in certain situations, for example, when trying to copy a file into a user directory, but the directory doesn't exist yet)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already check and made yourself sure that 2008.csv exists. That's why I think the permissions on this file not allowing you to copy it.

try: `sudo -u hdfs cat 2008.csv`

If you get permission denied error, this is your issue. Arrange permissions of the file or create a new one if so. If again you get "no file" error, try to use whole path for the file like:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /user/home/csvFiles/2008.csv /user/home/cloudera/Desktop
```

Comment: I got "hdfs is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported" after i tried to run that command

Comment: just try to open or edit 2008.csv, by using only cat or vi, or manually. It is only to ensure you have the permission to reach the file.

Comment: I have permission to read and write the file, however it still says that the file does not exist, which is strange.

Comment: Can u please try to give the full path of the file like at the bottom of my answer in your command then?

Comment: Also, when I use hadoop dfs  it says DEPRECATED: Use of this script for hdfs command is deprecated.

Comment: Well, we can go with hdfs dfs then, let me edit there

Comment: ok here is the command I tried: `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal 2008.csv user/home/cloudera/Desktop. `

Comment: Ok, please try to give the full path where 2008.csv is located like: hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /user/home/csvFiles/2008.csv /user/home/cloudera/Desktop

Comment: the location of the file I had to correct. I typed in 'hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /user/home/2008.csv home/cloudera/Desktop' The answer was : 'home/cloudera/Desktop' no such file or directory exists. The location is home/cloudera/Desktop

Comment: Working now or not? If not, can you please give me the full path of 2008.csv is located. /user/home/cloudera/Desktop is the path where you want to copy your csv file, it is your destination and it is already in your command. We need to add the source, location of the csv, and I think it will fix.

Comment: It is still not working. The full path of the file is /home/cloudera/Desktop/2008.csv

Comment: The full path of the file is /home/cloudera/Desktop/2008.csv  The file location states that it is /home/cloudera/Desktop